# Loading in local fonts with webpack 2 and the vue-cli

Tags: fonts, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

I'm using the vue-cli webpack template and I'm trying to load in local fonts in my project. I'm having trouble getting the path to my fonts correct. How should my path look like?

I found some information about what I might be doing wrong but I couldn't figure it out: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url

File structure:

[image]

In my _fonts.scss:

```
    // Webfont: LatoLatin-Regular
@font-face {
  font-family: 'LatoLatinWeb';
  src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoLatin-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoLatin-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
        url('../assets/fonts/LatoLatin-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */
        url('../assets/fonts/LatoLatin-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
        url('../assets/fonts/LatoLatin-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Webpack.base.config.sj:

```
  {
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  }
```

Utils.js:

```
  return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass').concat(
      {
        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
        options: {
          resources: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/_variables.scss')
        }
      }
    ).concat(
      {
        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
        options: {
          resources: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/mixins/_mixins.scss')
        }
      }      
    ).concat(
      {
        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
        options: {
          resources: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/_fonts.scss')
        }
      }      
    ),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
  }
```

How do I load my local fonts in with vue-cli webpack template?

Answer (score 13):

I import my fonts this way:

```
$font_path: '~@/assets/fonts/';

// *********** //
// SOURCE SANS //
// ITALIC
@font-face{
  font-family    : 'Source Sans Pro';
  src            : url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat; Modes */
  src            : url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */ url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Italic.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern Browsers */
  font-style     : italic, oblique;
  font-weight    : 400;
  text-rendering : optimizeLegibility;
}
// REGULAR
@font-face{
  font-family    : 'Source Sans Pro';
  src            : url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat; Modes */
  src            : url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */ url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern Browsers */
  font-style     : normal;
  font-weight    : 400;
  text-rendering : optimizeLegibility;
}
// SEMI BOLD
@font-face{
  font-family    : 'Source Sans Pro';
  src            : url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Semibold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat; Modes */
  src            : url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Semibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */ url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Semibold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */ url($font_path +'SourceSansPro-Semibold.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern Browsers */
  font-style     : normal;
  font-weight    : 600;
  text-rendering : optimizeLegibility;
}
// Use "font-family: $source_sans_pro" in your code.
$source_sans_pro : 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
// [END] SOURCE SANS //
// ***************** //
```

All my fonts are located in `src/assets/fonts/`

My `webpack.base.conf` file contains this loader:

```
 {
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

Comment: Worked for me after getting stuck and forgetting that relative paths don't work. Thank you!

Comment: Great. not having svg fonts will help imcluding svg images :)

Answer (score 1):

In the vuejs project I am working on,

This one did not worked:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'name-of-choice';
   src: url("~@/assets/<location-to-your-font-file>/font-file-name.ttf") format('font-type');
}
```

This worked:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'name-of-choice';
   src: url(~@/assets/<location-to-your-font-file>/font-file-name.ttf) format('font-type');
}
```

And I've observed that if we use the solution without double quote for one single time and then add double quotes, it again works! If anyone know what's happening here, please do answer.

Solution:
**Try not enclosing**  URL String in **quotes**.