# vue-init. Can't resolve fonts when npm run unit

Tags: javascript, webpack, fonts, vue.js, karma-runner

I have project, created using `vue-init` with webpack and tests

I added custom fonts, created using "icomoon", to my project, like this

In `main.js`:

```
import './main.scss'
```

In `main.scss`:

```
@import './assets/fonts/icons/style.scss';
```

In `style.scss`

```
@import 'variables';

@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/icomoon.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
...
```

And in `variables.scss`

```
$icomoon-font-path: './assets/fonts/icons/fonts' !default;
...
```

Project structure looks like this:

```
src
|-assets
| |-fonts
| |   icons
| |   |-fonts
| |   | |-icomoon.svg
| |   | |-icomoon.ttf
| |   | |-icomoon.woff
| |   |-style.scss
| |   |-variables.scss
| |-...
|-...
|-main.js
|-main.scss
|-...
```

When I trying to execute `npm run unit`, I receive errors like this:

```
...

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"minimize":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{}!./src/assets/fonts/icons/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/fonts/icons/fonts/icomoon.woff' in '/Users/administrator/projects/front-end-landing/src/assets/fonts/icons'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"minimize":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{}!./src/assets/fonts/icons/style.scss 6:188-238
 @ ./src/assets/fonts/icons/style.scss
 @ ./src ^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)
 @ ./test/unit/index.js

...

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Cannot find module "./assets/fonts/icons/fonts/icomoon.ttf"
  at http://localhost:9877webpack:///src/assets/fonts/icons/style.scss:6:0 <- index.js:39212
```

But at the same time, if I'll run project using `npm run dev`, icons works fine, I can see them and they are loading successfully

So, my question is, what I am doing wrong, why when I trying to run tests, icons not loaded properly?

Answer (score 4):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760741/loading-in-local-fonts-with-webpack-2-and-the-vue-cli)

Actually, the solution - include fonts like this

`$font_path: '~@/assets/fonts/';`

i.e. `~@/` at the beginning