# vue.js cli project not loading local fonts

Tags: webpack, vue.js, resolve-url-loader

There seems to be many issues around loading fonts on vue.js projects, I am using a webpack build and my

> build/webpack.base.conf.js

URL loader looks as follows:

> ```
>   {
>     test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
>     loader: 'url-loader',
>     options: {
>       limit: 10000,
>       name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
>     }
> ```

Inside my src folder I have

> assets/fonts/Radomir Tinkov - Gilroy-Regular.otf

And my App.vue contains the following code:

```
<style lang="scss">

//fonts

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  src: url("assets/fonts/Radomir Tinkov - Gilroy-Regular.otf") format("otf");
}
```

In my terminal I get the following error:

This relative module was not found:

```
* ./assets/fonts/Radomir%20Tinkov%20-%20Gilroy-Regular.otf in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
```

How do you define the correct font paths in vue.js?

Comment: Could you try `font-face { src: url(~@/assets/blah/font.otf);}`?  Pretty sure I know the exact issue your running into.

Comment: Also, please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45760741/691711

Comment: Hey @zero298 your above path seems to have worked. Is it possible to establish an entire folder as the source? Thanks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I don't think that `font-face` would understand globbing.  Can you provide a little more detail on what you mean?

Comment: I had a search online, it seems like for every font-style, you must create another instance of 'font-face'. I have included all the instances into a separate `./assets/scss/_fonts.scss` file which I am having to directly import in every component with `@import '~@/assets/scss/fonts'` Is there a less repetitive way of doing this?

Comment: I would import into your app's entrypoint component.  Are you using `scoped`?  If you aren't, the imported style should apply, or at least be available to, all components.

Answer (score 2):

In the vuejs project I am working on,

This one not worked:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'name-of-choice';
   src: url("~@/assets/<location-to-your-font-file>/font-file-name.ttf") format('font-type');
}
```

This worked:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'name-of-choice';
   src: url(~@/assets/<location-to-your-font-file>/font-file-name.ttf) format('font-type');
}
```

And I've observed that if we use the solution without double quote for one single time and then add double quotes, it again works!

Solution:
**Try without double-quotes**, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked removing `@font-face` and use font-family inside selector, example:

```
* {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  src: url(../../public/fonts/Roboto_Condensed/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf) format('font-type');
}
```